# Need answer for drupal question for upwork test

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I need to appear for up-work test.
I found this link http://upworktestru.com/drupal-test-upwork-answers-questions/ which has almost all the question.

But this link have only 25 question.

Can anyone help me out for the rest of answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need help with a specific question then ask it. No one here will take the test for you.

Answer (score 1):

Stack overflow is not a website that will help you cheat on tests. If you don't know the answers, there is a very good reason that you don't. And with this mindset you will never learn truly the answers.
So instead of asking us to answer the test, make yourself a good thing and read/become better by learning. It's multiple choice after all.

*Conclusion: Nobody will tell you the answers. That's life. Read. Evolve. Produce.*